# Roulette Wheel Selection in Genetic Algorithm using Golang

Tags: algorithm, go, artificial-intelligence

I'm building a mock roulette wheel selection function for genetic algorithm. First of, I would want to add up the `sum` of the `fitnessScore` in the main function. After adding up the `fitnessScore` I wanted to randomize a value out of that `sum` using the `math/rand` package in Go. How should I use the rand package in this scenario how do I fix `spin_wheel := rand.sum` in order to random a value?

```
package main

import(
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "math/rand"
)

func rouletteWheel(fitnessScore []float64) []float64{
    sum := 0.0
    for i := 0; i < len(fitnessScore); i++ {
        sum += fitnessScore[i]
    }

    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    spin_wheel := rand.sum
    partial_sum := 0.0
    for i := 0; i < len(fitnessScore); i++{
        partial_sum += fitnessScore[i]
        if(partial_sum >= spin_wheel){
            return fitnessScore
        }
    }
    return fitnessScore
}

func main(){
    fitnessScore := []float64{0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4}
    fmt.Println(rouletteWheel(fitnessScore))
}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what you're trying to do? I don't personally see how your code emulates a roulette wheel at all... A roulette wheel contains 34 discrete values. For some reason you're doing a sum and using real numbers, I don't see how either apply to the game of roulette? As I understand it you should just be doing `rand.Int31n(33)` to produce a number between 0-33, adding 1 to get the value of the roulette wheel since it's not zero indexed and reserving indexes 32 and 33 to represent the 0 and 00 values.

Comment: I don't see how this could compile. `rand.sum` would be unexported from rand; it may exist, but code in package main couldn't get at it. Also `for i := 0; i < len(fitnessScore); i++` seems less idiomatic than `for i, _ := range fitnessScore` or `for _, v := range fitnessScore { sum += v }`. I agree with evanmcdonnal; it doesn't look like a simulation of a roulette wheel. However, if you explain the requirements, it may not matter what you call it.

Comment: This is not the ordinary roulette wheel method. Its part of the genetic algorithm provided by [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9JzFcGdpT8E). The author of the video uses Java and I'm porting it into Golang. And yes I realize rand.sum issue, this is why I'm requesting assistance to fix it. Any idea guys?

Comment: Please explain what your problem is. Please don't expect us to go and watch that video. If all you want to achieve is setting a random seed for rand, do that once in init(), and it's done. I would suggest you don't do that initially, as a repeatable sequence of random numbers may make testing and debugging easier.

Comment: @gbulmer If you look at the line before `spin_wheel := rand.sum` I did add a random seed. The problem is I do not know how to generate a random value from the `sum` after adding up all the `fitnessScore`. In Python usually I will just do `spin_wheel = random() * sum`

Comment: My guess is that your intention is `urand(sum)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

// Returns the selected weight based on the weights(probabilities)
// Fitness proportionate selection:
// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitness_proportionate_selection
func rouletteSelect(weights []float64) float64 {
    // calculate the total weights
    sum := 0.0
    for _, weight := range weights {
        sum += weight
    }
    // get a random value
    value := rand.Float64() * sum
    // locate the random value based on the weights
    for _, weight := range weights {
        value -= weight
        if value <= 0 {
            return weight
        }
    }
    // only when rounding errors occur
    return weights[len(weights)-1]
}

func main() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    weights := []float64{0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4}
    fmt.Println(rouletteSelect(weights))
}
```

Comment: Current solution return a round number. What if I want to return decimal number?

Comment: @zuma89: Do you want this revised solution?